# デプロイが失敗してしまいます。ssh接続のログが出ていてそこで落ちるが解決策がわからないです

Tags: aws, capistrano, circleci

デプロイが失敗してしまうのですが、ログによるとssh接続のあたりで落ちます。
つい数日前ではデプロイできていたのですが、なぜか落ちる様になりました。

**環境:**
AWS、CircleCIを通したGitHubからの自動デプロイ時です。（Capistrano）

```
00:16 git:check
01 git ls-remote git@github.com:xxxxx/xxxxxx.git HEAD
01 Permission denied (publickey).
01 Permission denied (publickey).
01 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
01
01 Please make sure you have the correct access rights
01 and the repository exists.
...
略
...

Caused by:
SSHKit::Command::Failed: git exit status: 128
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

昨日、他作業の関係でssh-agentを初めて使用しました。
もしかしたら、その設定が怪しいのかな？と思いましたがよくわかりません。

エラーを元に以下など実行し再度デプロイしますが、何度実行しても同じところでデプロイが失敗します。

[CapistranoでEC2への自動デプロイ時、SSHキー認証エラーが出たときの対処法](https://laptrinhx.com/capistranodeec2heno-zi-dongdepuroi-shi-sshki-ren-zhengeraga-chutatokino-dui-chu-fa-3626328739/)

> ```
> eval `ssh-agent`
> ssh-add -K id_rsa
> ssh-add -K xxxxxxxxxxxxxx_rsa（デプロイ先の公開鍵）
> ```

この設定をすればGitHubとの連携はできているはず？と思うのですが・・

急ぎの件でして、何かアドバイスだけでも頂けましたら幸いです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: GitHub のトラブルシューティングガイド [Error: Permission denied (publickey) - GitHub Docs](https://docs.github.com/ja/github/authenticating-to-github/error-permission-denied-publickey) が参考になるかもしれません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

y_waiwai さん、metropolisさん

ありがとうございます！
最終的には、サーバーの容量不足（使用率100%）がこの問題の根幹でした..
エラーログに出ていたホストのサーバー容量を改善した事で解決できました！

内容確認してくださりありがとうございました！

Answer (score 1):

> git stderr: Permission denied (publickey).

このエラーは、接続鍵が間違っている場合に出ます。
そこらへん見直してみては